# Work, energy and power of massive spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, spring, continuum-mechanics

> The question is like if the spring of unstretched length $L$ has mass $M$ with one end fixed to the rigid support and it is made up of uniform wire then what kinetic energy is possessed if the free end is pulled with constant velocity?

I tried this question.
 If the free end is pulled with uniform velocity then that means there is no acceleration and initially the block of mass M was at rest position so it does not contain any kinetic energy initially due to pulling of the free it has virtue of kinetic energy so it might be $\frac12 mv^2$. 
But the answer given is $\frac 16 mv^2$.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kinetic energy of a massive spring](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/315675/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spring is being pulled only at one of its end. So, not all of the spring's length will move at the same velocity $v$.For this you need to take an infinitesimally small segment of the spring $dx$ at a distance x from the free end.

$dm =\frac{M}{L} dx $

Now velocity of each element will be proportional to its length-

$v'=\frac {vy}{L} $

Kinetic energy of this mass element will be given by

$K.E.=\frac {1}{2}dmv'^2$

Integrating this mass element's  $KE$ with proper limits, we will get the kinetic energy of the whole spring.

$$K.E.=\int_0^L \frac {1}{2}dmv'^2 $$

Upon substituting the values you will get your answer. (This I leave it to you!)