# Stretching of massive spring and it's kinetic energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, spring

While deriving the expression for the kinetic energy possessed by a massive spring (of mass $m$ and length $l$) when one of the ends is pulled constantly by a velocity $v_0$ while the other end being fixed to a wall (or simply rendered motionless), my physics teacher used following arguments/statements.

> [image: diagram]
> If spring stretches uniformly 
> $\frac{v}{x} = \frac{v_0}{l} $($v$ being the velocity of an infinitesimally small element of the spring at a distance $ x$)
> $ \Rightarrow v =(\frac{v_0}{l})x$
> With this, the kinetic energy of spring becomes
> $K_{spring} = \int_0^l \frac{1}{2} (\frac{m}{l}) {\rm d}x \frac{v^2}{l^2}x^2 \\ {\rm Thus, \space} K_{spring}= \frac{1}{6} mv_0^2    $

My problem is, if the spring is stretching uniformly, how can we say that $\frac{v}{x} = \frac{v_0}{l}$. I've trouble visualising the situation.

---

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/315675/kinetic-energy-of-a-massive-spring?

Comment: I'm afraid, it indeed answers my question. Thanks

Comment: @SteelCubes If the spring is stretching  uniformly hence $\frac{dv}{dx}=\text{constant}=a$ if you make this Ansatz $~v(x)=a\,x+b~$ with $~v(0)=0~,v(l)=v_l~$ you obtain $~v(x)=\frac{v_l}{l}\,x$